# WordPress add a new page to admin section

Tags: wordpress

I have already developed my plugin for WordPress and I can manage it from admin. I have passed the access to the plugin file using `add_submenu_page`. The problem is that the plugin is extending and I want to use another file that is linked from the main file. For example I have `second_page.php?id=3`. When I try to access this link, I get a

> You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

message. I want to "validate" this page also for using with this script and I don't know how. Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since WP natively supports URLs like `wp-admin/admin.php?page=<your_page_handle>` you can do sub pages with something like:

`wp-admin/admin.php?page=yourpage`

`wp-admin/admin.php?page=yourpage&sub=2`

`wp-admin/admin.php?page=yourpage&sub=3`

Then in the code that handles `wp-admin/admin.php?page=<your_page_handle>` you just look at the $_GET and pull up the main page or a sub-page as needed.

I've definitely seen plugins where the admin page has a little row of links across the top linking the various sub-pages.

Answer (score 6):

When you add a page with `add_submenu_page()`, the url should be something like:

`wp-admin/admin.php?page=<your_page_handle>`

Your page is actually loaded from `admin.php` (typically). You can add parameters to your links by appending something like `&id=3` and then have your main plugin page-loading logic determine which file to include based on the parameter.

For instance

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && ((int) $_GET['id']) == 3) {
  include 'second_page.php';
} else {
  include 'first_page.php';
}
```

Edit:

I found a trick that may be easier for you, though I haven't thoroughly tested it. Let's say that you have two pages: `my_one` and `my_two`. Just call `add_submenu_page` twice, and set the second page's parent as the first page. This will cause Wordpress to not add a link to the navigation bar, but you can still access your page by navigating to `admin.php?page=my_two`.

Example:

```
    add_submenu_page( 
          'my_toplevel_link'   
        , 'Page Title'
        , 'Link Name'
        , 'administrator'
        , 'my_one' // here's the page handle for page one
        , 'my_one_callback'
    );
    add_submenu_page( 
          'my_one'  // set the parent to your first page and it wont appear
        , 'Page Title'
        , 'Link Name'  // unused
        , 'administrator'
        , 'my_two'
        , 'my_two_callback'
    );
```

Comment: Well, I know how to include one page like page.php, how about page.php?id=3 ? This changes everything and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: 5 years later, and this answer is still useful. However @FletcherMoore do you know how I can make it so that `my_toplevel_link` still remains selected as the **main** menu?

Comment: Wow. Sorry. I don't even remember anything about Wordpress or what I was writing here. It has been too long.